# Missing custom screen in Acumatica customization project

Tags: acumatica

I’m experiencing an issue with customization projects in Acumatica 2017 R2 Build 17.203.0029.

Specifically, custom screens, while in my project XML, are not visible within the customization project browser nor can they be navigated to once published (which occurs without error). This only occurs on my staging server. Everything works fine in my local dev environment and even on a different instance of Acumatica. My local dev environment matches the staging server in every possible way (Acumatica version, other packages, etc.)

Older versions of the same customization project have been published before and did not exhibit this behavior. It’s only after I replaced the project with newer version of the same project that I encounter the missing custom screen issue.

As shown in the screenshot below, remnants of the custom screens are present in the Customized Screens window. And the ASPX files are present and shown in the Custom Files window.

[Screenshot of missing custom screen data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6kPY.png)

When I compare the “Edit Project Items” objects between the staging the server and my local dev version, they appear the same.

It it possible that the internal customization or sitemap tables on the staging server have inconsistent data? Is there anyway to rebuild them?

Comment: Try deleting all pages and folders related to that customization in the sitemap. After that use 'publish with cleanup' to republish the customization. This should re-create the sitemap. Are you able to access the pages manually? like that: http://website/instance/Main?ScreenId=XX000000 (replace website, instance and XX000000 with appropriate values for your deployment)

Comment: By the way, the missing screens entry in your screenshot is normal if you open the project before publishing it. After successful sitemap publishing they should appear though.

Comment: I've tried your recommendations: Removing all previous site map entries related to the customization and then choosing "Publish with Cleanup". No errors occured during publishing and the project shows that it's been published, but still I cannot access my custom screens. They cannot be accessed by URL convention either.

Comment: Perhaps another clue that points to a site map issue, the customization project also contains several GI's. These too cannot be accessed by URL convention, though accessing them via the Generic Inquiry screen (SM208000) and clicking "View Inquiry" does show them though strangely the URL in the location bar changes to &ScreenId=00000000 instead of what it should be (e.g. &ScreenId=GI000016). All custom GI's were also manually removed from the site map before "Publish With Cleanup".

Comment: HBAcumatica, I think I've figured this out. The solution appears related to the users roles config. See answer below. Sorry for the false alarm. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution appears related to the users roles config. I had not assigned access rights to the custom forms. Doing so solved the issue. The custom screens are now accessible by direct URL and are shown in the customization project browser. Maybe this will help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue when trying to Deploy the customization to another instance.

To fix it I had to go to the site manager and change the URL of the new page

from: "/Pages/SO/CustomName"

to: "~/Pages/SO/CustomName"